# Not able to use wifi after installing ubuntu on bootable external hard disk

Tags: wireless, live-usb

I am very new to ubuntu. I installed it on an external hard drive using my mac to try it. I used the bootable stick on my mac, but i am encountering some problems. When i try to connect to wifi, a page saying "No Wi-Fi adapter found" comes. What should i do? I cannot use an ethernet if that is of any use.

Thank you

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: it is version 20.04

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that you didn't install proprietary drivers in the initial install.

just get a hold of your ubuntu.iso and mount it like this,

```
sudo mkdir /media/cdrom
cd ~
sudo mount -o loop [path-to]ubuntu.iso /media/cdrom
```

The above code will mount your iso as loopback cd-rom device...

now,
open `software & updates` and look for the install from `cd-rom` and then install your wireless drivers from there.

good luck

Comment: It just says "mount: /media/cdrom: failed to setup loop device for [path-to]ubuntu.iso"

Comment: you need to give the path to the ubuntu iso

Comment: Whenever you are free could you tell what exactly I have to do to give the path to the ubuntu iso? I am new to command line. Thank you very much.

Comment: `path` is just the location of a file:)